# Why does it take 2 minutes for the request to timeout when my timeout is only 1 minute?

Tags: java, android, http, request

I'm not sure why this is happening and I've already searched the internet why this is happening but I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Basically this happens when I try to send a request when the *Wi-Fi is off* and the *mobile data is ON* **but** there is *no data*. It takes 2 minutes for the exception to be thrown. I wanna know the proper reason why. The timeouts are these:

```
urlconn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
urlconn.setReadTimeout(60000);
```

Does this mean that both timeouts occur that's why it took 2 minutes or are there other reason that I'm not aware of why this is happening?

Note: I can only post a code snippet due to confidentiality reasons.

Comment: It's probably a DNS timeout. The exception and stack trace will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are occurring. There's no data, so the connection fails, that's one minute. Then there's nothing to read from a stream that doesn't exist due to no connection, that's another minute.

Comment: Absolute and utter nonsense. The read can't possibly execute if there wasn't a connection.

Comment: @EJP This is what I was thinking also but when I tried lowering both to 5 seconds, the exception is printed in 13 seconds.